# set focus on tab layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tabs

I need help with my current problem:

1. so i was creating an app which the main menu contain certain button (5 button), and when you press the button, the submenu activity will start.
2. the submenu activity contain sliding tab layout that i create by following some tutorial on internet, and it inflating 5 different layout depend on the position index.
3. the tab layout is working fine.

my problem :
what i'm trying to do is, when i press button 1, it will start the submenu activity and tablayout with position index 1 will be focused, and when i press button 2, it will do the same but the tablayout with position index 2 will be focused. but it seems i can't figure it out, so i need help anyone, thanks.

first, here's my main menu xml :

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.MenuUtama" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_action_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Button 0"
                android:onClick="btn0"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:onClick="btn1"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_1" />
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:onClick="btn2"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_2" />

        </LinearLayout>
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Button 3"
                android:onClick="btn3"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_3" />
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Button 4"
                android:onClick="btn4"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_4" />
                 
        </LinearLayout>
        
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then my SubMenu xml:

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.SubMenu" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_action_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar" />

    <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/MyPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my main menu.java :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity {

 private Toolbar toolbar;
    String level;
    TextView text;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);
        
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_action_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  
  
    }
 
 public void btn0(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMenu.class));
 }
 public void btn1(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMenu.class));
 }
 public void btn2(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMenu.class));
 }
 public void btn3(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMenu.class));
 }
 public void btn4(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMenu.class));
 }
   
 
}
```

next is my submenu.java :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import tabs.SlidingTabLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SubMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

 private Toolbar toolbar;
 private ViewPager mPager;
 private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);
  
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_action_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

  mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.MyPager);
  mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

  mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyTabs);
  mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
  mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
  mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
  mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
 }

 class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  String[] tabsText;

  public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm);
   tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
   return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   return tabsText[position];
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return 5;
  }

 }

 public static class MyFragment extends Fragment implements
   OnItemClickListener {
  public static int posisi;
  
  public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
   MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putInt("position", position);
   myFragment.setArguments(args);
   return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    @Nullable ViewGroup container,
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,
     false);
   Bundle bundle = getArguments();
   posisi = bundle.getInt("position");   
   
   switch (posisi) {
   case 0:
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_0, container, false);
    break;
   case 1:
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    break;
   case 2:
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    break;
   case 3:
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);
    break;
   case 4:
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_4, container, false);
    break;
   default:
    break;
   }
   return layout;

  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }

 }

}
```

i'm using this SlidingTabStrip.java and SlidingTabLayout.java from the tutorial :

SlidingTabStrip.java:

```js
package tabs;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {
 private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
 private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
 private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
 private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;
 private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
 private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;
 private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
 private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;
 private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;
 private int mSelectedPosition;
 private float mSelectionOffset;
 private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
 private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

 SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
  this(context, null);
 }

 SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  setWillNotDraw(false);
  final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
  TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
  context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue,
    true);
  final int themeForegroundColor = outValue.data;
  mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
    DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);
  mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
  mDefaultTabColorizer
    .setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);
  mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
  mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
  mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);
  mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
  mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
 }

 void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
  mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
  invalidate();
 }

 void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
  // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
  mCustomTabColorizer = null;
  mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
  invalidate();
 }

 void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
  mSelectedPosition = position;
  mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
  invalidate();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  final int height = getHeight();
  final int childCount = getChildCount();
  final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null ? mCustomTabColorizer
    : mDefaultTabColorizer;
  // Thick colored underline below the current selection
  if (childCount > 0) {
   View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
   int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
   int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
   int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);
   if (mSelectionOffset > 0f
     && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
    int nextColor = tabColorizer
      .getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
    if (color != nextColor) {
     color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
    }
    // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
    View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
    left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset)
      * left);
    right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset)
      * right);
   }
   mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);
   canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
     height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
  }
  // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
  canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height,
    mBottomBorderPaint);
 }

 /**
  * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha}
  * value.
  */
 private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
  return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color),
    Color.blue(color));
 }

 /**
  * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
  * 
  * @param ratio
  *            of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will
  *            give an even blend, 0.0 will return {@code color2}.
  */
 private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
  final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
  float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio)
    + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
  float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio)
    + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
  float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio)
    + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
  return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
 }

 private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements
   SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
  private int[] mIndicatorColors;

  @Override
  public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
   return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
  }

  void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
   mIndicatorColors = colors;
  }
 }
}
```

SlidingTabLayout.java :

```js
package tabs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
 /**
  * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
  * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
  */
 public interface TabColorizer {
  /**
   * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position}
   *         is selected.
   */
  int getIndicatorColor(int position);
 }

 private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
 private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
 private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;
 private int mTitleOffset;
 private int mTabViewLayoutId;
 private int mTabViewTextViewId;
 private boolean mDistributeEvenly;
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
 private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;
 private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

 public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
  this(context, null);
 }

 public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  this(context, attrs, 0);
 }

 public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  // Disable the Scroll Bar
  setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
  setFillViewport(true);
  mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources()
    .getDisplayMetrics().density);
  mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
  addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 }

 /**
  * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
  * 
  * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
  * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve similar effects.
  */
 public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
  mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
 }

 public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
  mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
 }

 /**
  * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors
  * are treated as a circular array. Providing one color will mean that all
  * tabs are indicated with the same color.
  */
 public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
  mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
 }

 /**
  * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using
  * {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are required to set any
  * {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
  * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
  * 
  * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
  */
 public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
  mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
 }

 /**
  * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
  * 
  * @param layoutResId
  *            Layout id to be inflated
  * @param textViewId
  *            id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
  */
 public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
  mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
  mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
 }

 /**
  * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the
  * pager content (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this
  * call has been made.
  */
 public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
  mTabStrip.removeAllViews();
  mViewPager = viewPager;
  if (viewPager != null) {
   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
   populateTabStrip();
  }
 }

 /**
  * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab
  * view is not set via {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
  */
 protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
  TextView textView = new TextView(context);
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
  textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
  getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(
    android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
  textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
  textView.setAllCaps(true);
  int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources()
    .getDisplayMetrics().density);
  textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  return textView;
 }

 private void populateTabStrip() {
  final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
  final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();
  for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
   View tabView = null;
   TextView tabTitleView = null;
   if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
    // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate
    // it
    tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
      mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip, false);
    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView
      .findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
   }
   if (tabView == null) {
    tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
   }
   if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
   }
   if (mDistributeEvenly) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView
      .getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 0;
    lp.weight = 1;
   }
   tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
   tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
   String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
   if (desc != null) {
    tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
   }
   mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
   if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
    tabView.setSelected(true);
   }
  }
 }

 public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
  mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  if (mViewPager != null) {
   scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
  }
 }

 private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
  final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
  if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0
    || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
   return;
  }
  View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
  if (selectedChild != null) {
   int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;
   if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
    // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure
    // we obey the offset
    targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
   }
   scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
  }
 }

 private class InternalViewPagerListener implements
   ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
  private int mScrollState;

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
    int positionOffsetPixels) {
   int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
   if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0)
     || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
    return;
   }
   mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);
   View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
   int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null) ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle
     .getWidth()) : 0;
   scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);
   if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position,
      positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
   mScrollState = state;
   if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
    scrollToTab(position, 0);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
    mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
   }
   if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
   }
  }
 }

 private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
     return;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```